# How to return a default value if no match is found in search of string

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, default

Suppose I have a string like `"a-1_b-2_c-3_d-4"` with numbers, labels, and separators, and I want to get `{a-> 1, b-> 2, c-> 3, d-> 4}`, I can do something like:

```
string1 = "a-1_b-2_c-3_d-4";
vals = ToExpression /@ StringCases[string1, 
{"a-" ~~ a : NumberString -> a, 
"b-" ~~ b : NumberString -> b, 
"c-" ~~ c : NumberString -> c, 
"d-" ~~ d : NumberString -> d}];
result = Thread[{a, b, c, d} -> vals]

{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4}
```

But sometimes my input has one or more parts missing and I would like the default value to be zero in those cases so that `"a-1_d-4"` becomes `{a -> 1, b -> 0, c -> 0, d -> 4}`.  I can't think of a way to do this other than search for each value individually and then check to see if the result was empty.  Is there a cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
assoc = AssociationThread[{a, b, c, d}, {0, 0, 0, 0}];
string1 = "a-1_d-4";

AssociateTo[
 assoc, 
 AssociationThread @@ 
  Transpose[
   Partition[
    StringCases[StringReplace[string1, "-" -> " "], 
     x : NumberString | "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" :> ToExpression[x]], 
    2]]
 ];
assoc
```

> <|a -> 1, b -> 0, c -> 0, d -> 4|>

You can use `Normal` on this if you really need a list of rules.

Comment: That definitely works for my example, except it treats the - as a negative sign but that is not really an issue.  I will mark this as an answer because it does work for the test case. I need to tweak it a bit to get it to work for my more general input but  `AssociateTo` was the key (pun intended) I needed.

Comment: Ah, I see. Fixed it now. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for my actual input which is not as simple as the example data I gave. It is inspired by Schumacher's answer but not nearly as neat.

```
string2 = "0deg_5kV_60mA_10A_Y1-1.5A";
assoc2 = AssociationThread[{deg, kV, mA, A, X1, Y1, X2, Y2}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}];
StringSplit[string2, "_"]
StringCases[#,""|"-"~~x:NumberString|"deg"|"kV"|"mA"|"A"|"X1"|"X2"|"Y1"|"Y2"
  :>ToExpression[x]] & /@ %
%[[;; , ;; 2]] (*Gets rid of the extra A*)
ReverseSort /@ %
AssociateTo[assoc2, AssociationThread @@ Transpose@%] 

{"0deg", "5kV", "60mA", "10A", "Y1-1.5A"}  
{{0, deg}, {5, kV}, {60, mA}, {10, A}, {Y1, 1.5, A}}  
{{0, deg}, {5, kV}, {60, mA}, {10, A}, {Y1, 1.5}}
{{deg, 0}, {kV, 5}, {mA, 60}, {A, 10}, {Y1, 1.5}}
<|deg -> 0, kV -> 5, mA -> 60, A -> 10, X1 -> 0, Y1 -> 1.5, X2 -> 0, Y2 -> 0|>
```